# How to know if there is a previous page

Tags: javascript

I was trying to figure out how to know the if the user can basically go back a page.
I looked at `history.length` but it's not consistant browser-wise (it's 1 on all on a new page except Firefox which returns 2) and it also counts the pages that are forward.

I basically have a form with a back button that should simply redirect to the home page in case the user can't navigate back.

Comment: Why don't you use a browser checker library to overcome that inconsistence?

Comment: `history.length` returns `1` for a new page for me, Firefox 56.0.2.

Comment: @Xufox same on chrome 62

Comment: @Dez Do you have any examples ?

Comment: @Xufox Might be because I did my tests on jsbin, but I can reliably use it anyway since it counts forward pages too